# Systemd activate unit on recovery / on first success after failure

Tags: systemd

Systemd provides the ability to activate other units when a unit enters the *inactive* state with the option `OnSuccess=notify-success@%n` or the *failed* state with `OnFailure=notify-failure@%n` as [documented](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). I use these to send me notifications on state changes.

I now have a unit where I want to be notified when a unit recovers from a failed state, meaning only when the unit runs successfully for the very first time after having been in a failed state (*failed* -> *active* -> *inactive*).

`OnSuccess` doesn't help here since it is executed every time the unit runs successfully.  I'm looking for an option like e.g. `OnFirstSuccess=notify-recovered@%n`. Does this possbility exist in systemd?